# Ubuntu 14.04 DVD drive won't work

Tags: 14.04, dvd

I just got a new DVD drive that I know works because it live boots another distribution. When I put a dvd into the drive it repeatedly tries and fails to spin up, and Ubuntu doesn't recognize that there is a dvd in the drive.

Here is the lshw output with:

No dvd in the drive:

```
*-cdrom
         description: DVD reader
         product: CDW/DVD TS-L462C
         vendor: TSSTcorp
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: TO10
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

With a dvd in the drive:

```
*-cdrom
         description: DVD reader
         product: CDW/DVD TS-L462C
         vendor: TSSTcorp
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: TO10
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

What should I do to get it running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Could be anything described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs 
I am experiencing the same issue with 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04 and it is **great** frustration.

On 15.10 I had partial success with `regionset` setting, but not permanent, plus I have DVDs from both EU and USA.

I would give this Fluendo player a shot, but it seems it does not support 16.04?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

1. `sudo mkdir /media/cdrom`
2. `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

   In the text editor, add this line:

   ```
   /dev/sr0    /media/cdrom udf,iso9660 ro,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
   ```

Comment: There's no point in an `fstab` entry, if the drive and/or the kernel don't recognise the medium.